# Corona SDK: TableView index not updating

Tags: indexing, lua, tableview, coronasdk

I've got a problem with Corona SDK and the tableview, but allow me to show the code first:

```
function functions.onRowTouch( event )
  print("ONROWTOUCH EXECUTING")

  if event.phase == "tap" or event.phase == "press" then
    print("EVENT.TARGET.INDEX: " .. event.target.index)
    editItemNum = event.target.index
    print("editnum: " .. editItemNum)
    print("ITEM tapped")
    if saveData.names[event.target.index] ~= nil then
        function functions.pressRow(event)
            print("ROW NUM: " .. event.target.index)
            print("EDITNUM = " .. editItemNum)
            functions.pressItem()
            return true
        end
        event.target:addEventListener("tap", functions.pressRow)
    end
  elseif event.phase == "swipeLeft" then
    print("SWIPING LEFT")
    tableView:deleteRows({event.target.index}, {slideLeftTransitionTime=450})
    table.remove(saveData.names, editItemNum)
    table.remove(saveData.dates, editItemNum)
    table.remove(saveData.amounts, editItemNum)
    loadsave.saveTable(saveData, "payMeBackTable.json")
    print("ROW DELETED")
  end
end
```

I'm sorry for the indentation, stackoverflow just kept changing it...
But here is my question:
in the event.phase == "tap", I'm assigning editItemNum to event.target.index. After that I delete a row that is tapped. This works great for the first time. I'm using this line of code to achieve that btw:

```
tableView:deleteRows({editItemNum}, {slideLeftTransitionTime=400} )
```

So the delete function knows what to delete because "editItemNum" gets the value of the row index.
But once I deleted the row, the index numbers of the rows are not adapting. So for example I've got 3 objects in my table: 1,2,3. Now I delete the middle one, so I should get: 1,2. But instead when I touch the second row, the index is still 3. So visually that'd look like: 1,3.
It just makes no sense in my eyes and I really don't see anything wrong with my code. I did find a post on the Corona SDK forums with a bug report for this issue, but that was 2 years ago and was resolved...
Any help? :)

Kind regards,
Bram

Comment: but your code contains this line: `tableView:deleteRows({event.target.index}, {slideLeftTransitionTime=450})` instead of `tableView:deleteRows({editItemNum}, {slideLeftTransitionTime=400} )` which you claim to use. I'm confused

Comment: What re you confused bout? Anyways, it's a confirmed bug!

Comment: "So the delete function knows what to delete because "editItemNum" gets the value of the row index."  but you don't use editItemNum in the deleteRows function. At least not in the provided code.
If it is a bug and it has been resolved make sure your sdk is up to date.

Comment: Woops, you are correct. It should be changed to editItemNum. But still, event.target.id does not get updated when you change the structure of the row (move, delete...). It's a bug and it has not been fixed yet.

Comment: @BramVanbilsen it looks like the problem in still there. Have you found a way around it? (sorry for updating such an old topic...)